# How to use Control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to modify GUI

Tags: c#

I need to modify the GUI from inside of a method that takes long time to finish. As I read other posts,
one of the solution is to use Control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to set the GUI inside the worker thread.
However, I don't have a clue how to do this here.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
        {
            ProcessFilesThree();
        });
    }

    private void ProcessFilesThree()
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\In", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) =>
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(currentFile);

                    // the following assignment is illegal
            this.Text = string.Format("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename,
                                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
        });

        this.Text = "All done!"; // <- this assignment is illegal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 msg = string.Format("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename,
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
 this.BeginInvoke( (Action) delegate ()
    {
        this.Text = msg;
    });
```

Comment: I like your solution but I don't know why it works. May you give me a little detail description for this usage? As I know, we should not update the GUI from a work thread. Then why we can update the GUI from a delegate asynchronously called on the worker thread?  -- thx

Comment: @q0987 - read the docs on Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, it will give you the answers you are looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx

Comment: The BeginInvoke method creates a windows message and posts the messages to the window.  ProcessMessage, running on the GUI thread, picks up the message and calls the delegate.  The delegate is lambda expression so has access the msg local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ProcessFilesThree()
{
   // Assuming you have a textbox control named testTestBox
   // and you wanted to update it on each loop iteration
   // with someMessage
   string someMessage = String.Empty;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(1000); //Simulate a second of work.
      someMessage = String.Format("On loop iteration {0}", i);
      testTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>((message) =>
      {
          testTextBox.Text = message;
      }), someMessage);

   }
}
```